# Как заполнить пустой массив объектами.

Tags: javascript

В таком виде - [{x:y} {x:y} {x:y}]; ?

Comment: а поконкретнее вопрос? нужна функция?

Comment: цикл надо......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, как у Вас, только с запятыми.

```js
var y = null;

var arr = [{ x: y }, { x: y }, { x: y }];
console.log(arr);

// или

var arr1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  arr1.push({ x: y });
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

через цикл

```js
let y = 'y';
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr.push({x:y});
}
console.log(arr);
```